# (C++) Cannot use string::substr to assign substrings to objects

Tags: c++, string

I am designing a cheat for the game WordBrain. Basically this is just a small program that takes a number of letters, permutes the sequence, then splits the sequence into 'words' which have length attribute, then search my text file to file meaningful permutation to print out.

```
    while (next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end())) //loop through possible permutations of the combination
    {
        int position_marker = 0; //serve specific purpose
        for (auto x : substring_collection) //trouble is in this loop
        {
            string temp;
            int k = x.take_length();
            try { temp = letters.substr(position_marker, k); }
            catch (out_of_range) { cout << "OUT OF RANGE"; }
            x.set(temp); //member content does not register change
            position_marker += x.take_length(); //also member word_length is 0 now, despite their are no invocation of methods capable of changing it
        }
        if (all_of(substring_collection.begin(), substring_collection.end(), [&](substring & s) {return !(library.find(s.take_content()) == library.end()); }))
        {
            for (auto x : substring_collection)
            {
                cout << x.take_content() + " ";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the location the trouble stems from. Basically, substring_collection is a `vector<substring>`, which contains objects of class `substring`
Here is how the class looks like:

```
class substring
{
private:
    std::string content;
    int word_length;
public:
    substring() : content(""), word_length(0) {};
    substring(std::string & s, int c) : content(s), word_length(c) {};
    void set(std::string & s)
    {
        content = s;
    }
    void clear()
    {
        content.clear();
    }
    void set_length(int c)
    {
        word_length = c;
    }
    void showinfo() const
    {
        std::cout << "Content is " + content << " Length is : " << word_length;
    }
    int take_length() const
    {
        return word_length;
    }  
    std::string take_content() const
    {
        return content;
    }  
};
```

I suspect that the reason the code goes wrong is `position_marker`, whose value depends on the member 'word_length' of the object `substring` is set to 0.
In the code prior to this loop, I only the setting method for this member to take data from users' input (from `std::cin`).
Can you please tell me that is there any hidden mechanism that reset the property, or create brand new objects that I did not aware of?
Also, teachings on coding styles are very welcomed. I just started learning to code so any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: You should probably include why you think it is failing on the line mentioned as well as a description of how it currently is not working/running as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll make sure to include how the bugs appear to be should there come other questions from me, in the future. For now, I have worked out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (auto x : substring_collection)
```

Here, `x` is of type `substring`. This is a *copy* of the element in the vector, and then when you modify it, you only modify the copy, not the original.

You'll have to use a reference to modify the original element in the vector

```
for (auto& x : substring_collection)
```

---

For why `word_length` is `0`, I don't know, it isn't in the code you posted. My guess would be that you `resize`d the vector, which called the default constructor of `substring`, which set `word_length` to `0`.

Comment: Thank you. You saved my life. It turned out to be exactly what you identified! The code acted on the copy of the substrings, and not the original one, hence when I tried to read input from cin into it, the original were not affected. I tried to use reference and now its working!